# Odoo xpath roat

Tags: xpath, odoo

This is code from original report. my goal is to put **my_field_name** before Product. how can i reach it with xpath.

```
            <table class="table table-condensed" t-if="o.pack_operation_ids">
                      <t t-set="has_barcode" t-value="any([pack_operation.product_id and pack_operation.product_id.sudo().barcode or pack_operation.package_id for pack_operation in o.pack_operation_ids])"/>
                      <t t-set="has_serial_number" t-value="o.pack_operation_ids.filtered('pack_lot_ids')" groups="stock.group_production_lot"/>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><strong>Product</strong></th>
                            <th class="text-right"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
                            <t t-if="o.picking_type_id.code != 'incoming'"><th><strong>Source</strong></th></t>
                            <th t-if="has_barcode" class="text-center">
                                <strong>Barcode</strong>
                            </th>
                            <th t-if="has_serial_number">
                                <strong>Lot/Serial Number</strong>
                            </th>
                            <t t-if="o.picking_type_id.code != 'outgoing'"><th><strong>Destination</strong></th></t>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xpath expr="//table[@t-if='o.pack_operation_ids']/thead/tr/th[1]" position="before">
 ------ your code goes here ------
</xpath
```

Please use above code for reference.